# How to return an object with an image inside of it using spring boot?

Tags: json, image, hibernate, spring-boot

How should I return a object with an image inside of it from a GET call (in a JSON form of course). Is the best approach to send it as a normal JSON object with an array of bytes? Also should that same image be saved in database as it is or just as a path to the picture in a folder?

Comment: a regular way to deal with image.At first save it in object save service like amazon s3.then get a uri for the image and save it in your db.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to return image in response as below:

1. return complete base64 of image in json response but its slow down for large size image.
2. first save image in file system at any location then return url in json response so best way and image can access easily with url but need to implement autherization if some important image.